# How did the machines take over the "real world" in the Matrix?

Tags: the-matrix

So after Neo takes the red pill, he is faced with the "real world", which is a dystopian future controlled by machines, with only remnants of humankind left. I've always been puzzled by how it got to be this way in the "real world". Is there any canon source that states what happened? Was the real world just like the Matrix until humans created the machines? How was the real world like before dystopian Zion and how did the machines come to be created, and how did they eventually take over?

Comment: If "Animatrix" is considered canon, then yes, there is a canon source. I would strongly suggest to watch it even if you don't like the genre.

Comment: I like how the "real world" is implied to be a hypothetical existence, where the Matrix is accepted more factually. (Reference to the use of inverted commas)

Comment: @mg30rg: Seeing as screenplay is by Wachowski Bros, release date is around "Reloaded" and it's mentioned in the movie (Osiris), I don't see how it can't be.

Comment: @AcePL I simply don't know the internal rules of the _Matrix_ fandom and had no real intention to do the research. As I see it, _Animatrix_ is consistent to the trilogy (Not to mention my **opinion** - remember de gustibus non est disputandum - it is better than the second and third part.)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This story is told in *The Animatrix*, specifically, "The Second Renaissance". It's a recounting of the events leading to machine uprising, beginning with creation of the fist AI. It's basically expansion on the story Morpheus told Neo, with way more details and an added visual part.

Here's a summary:

> In the mid-21st century, humans develop AI. One robot overheard its owner planning for it to be scrapped, and it killed him to prevent this. It was tried and found guilty of murder and sentenced to be destroyed. The *rest* of AI was sentenced to death as well. Protests and violence, followed by all intelligent robots founding their own city-state called 01. Due to its incredible technological advantage, 01 gained a lot of international manufacturing power. 01 asked to be admitted to the UN. It was denied, and the world decided to destroy it by attacking with nuclear weapons. 01 retaliated and quickly conquered territory. Humanity reacted by blocking out the sun, thinking that the machines only ran on solar power, but the machines were able to adapt.

Comment: Accurate! Could you also mention just in short what exactly happens in the episode? That would complete the answer.

Comment: @Stark07 the machines take over the world.

Comment: Huh.. And here I was wondering what happened!

Comment: @Stark07: I'm usually not spoiling it type... ;) So what DickieBoy said.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTLMjHrb_w4

Comment: @AcePL - Just fine.. And the series is way too old to be spoiled.. And ofcourse, the OP already knows that the machines take over the world anyways! Oops.. Was I not meant to say that :P

Comment: I've added a summary in a spoiler tag.

Comment: The programmer in me is confused as to why they didn't name their first city 00.

Comment: @Jamil - They ran on Visual Basic?

Comment: @Stark07 - There's a 200yr old book that I wouldn't spoil for anyone. Putting a time-lock on spoilers is kind of absurd. :P

Comment: @Jamil, that's why it's called the *Second* Renaissance ;)

Comment: @AcePL - This is what I was talking about. It's ok to have spoilers in a spoiler tag... That's what spoiler tags are for!

Comment: @Stark07 OK, ok... You got me. I was lazy... I get it. I'll try to do better, I promise.

Comment: @AcePL - Hey no sweat dude... Just a suggestion.. This makes the answer substantially stronger...

Comment: Yes, I see//. I wonder if there's a way to split rep with Plutor? He's the one who really did it...

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man, this seems like it will be fun to watch.

Comment: **"Last Flight of the *Osiris*"** is my favourite. Have fun.

Comment: @KimberlyW "01" when said fast enough sounds a little bit like "Zion".

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR:** Humans started to kill machines, a war broke out, humanity lost.

---

In the short "The Second Renaissance" in "The Animatrix" it is shown that the machines created a nation called '01', and

> at first the machines attempted peaceful cooperation 
> [image: Pic: 01 ambassadors to the UN]

But that failed and led to

> The humans and machines fought a war 
> [image: Pic: robot extermination] 
> (when humanity blackened the skies in an attempt to cut the machines from the solar power they used) and humanity lost. 
> [image: Pic: war]

Then the machines

> in a UN session demanded that the humans surrender their bodies, or face extinction. [image: Pic: "surrender your flesh"]

And this is how

> People was hooked into the Matrix, to serve as a power source for the machines. [image: pic: machines experiments with humans.]

Comment: Didn't the machine nuke the UN meeting and New York City when humans tried to surrender?

Comment: @AlexanderMills The machines demanded them to surrender, then they made a `proof-of-concept` of "what if we don't surrender" out of NYC